# Laravel - How to change response format for specific fields

Tags: laravel, model

I've "Product" model.
And need to change some value formats for only responses.

For example;

```
I've "price" on database as decimal (11,2).
I want this as "1.000.000,00" format on response.
```

Or created_at field to `"Carbon::parse($this->created_at)->toDayDatetimeString()"`

Or I want to add 3 specific columns with my user attribute, on response. (is_allowed etc.)

How can this be possible on model?
How can I response like that?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#custom-casts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Mutator and Accessor to set format :
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators

```
public function setDateAttribute($date) {
    $this->attributes['date'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date);
}

public function getFirstNameAttribute($value)
{
    return ucfirst($value);
}
```

Comment: i'm sorry to tell, this method does not format/change the value of an existing attribute, instead it makes new attribute that has new value. And also be careful not to put duplicate attribute else it will return an error.

Answer (score 0):

As a best practice in Laravel you can use Eloquent Resources: [Eloquent Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources)

It's basically a "transformer" between models data and API/Responses Output.
The only one thing to notice is that in the Resource files yout must specify all fields and relations (if needed) of the Model manually.

In the `toArray()` function you can modify the type of all data of your model as you prefer.
If not, you can access the new field by `$model->my_custom_field` (Laravel can resolve the name of the getter function automatically).

```
public function toArray($request)
    {
        $editedFieldValue = doSomething();
        return [
            'my_field' => $editedFieldValue,
            'other_field' => '',
        ];
    }
```

If you want to do that in Model, you can create customs fields:

```
class MuModel extends Model
{

    protected $appends = ['my_custom_field'];

    public function getMyCustomFiledAttribute(){

        $newData = doSomething($this->existent_field);

        return $newData;

    }
}
```

The `$appends` variable add the new fields to all responses generated from the Model, as a normal database field.

P.S.: You can create a getAttribute() function for existent database attribute and return the value as you want!

For example: `getCreatedAtAttribute()`